# Select multiple rows that match the same IDs requested

Tags: sql, mariadb

I can't seem to find anything like what I'm trying to do.

I have multiple IDs, for instance: 9044, 9044, 3832. Note how some IDs can be the same.

If I use IN to get this, such as:

```
select `name`, `value`, item_id
from items
where item_id IN (9044,9044,3832) and tradeable = 1
```

It will return only two results even though I requested for 3:

[image]

How can I modify my query to match the amount of items requested even if the item ids are the same? Thanks

Comment: You didn't request 3, but only two. Read the SQL specification.

Comment: My IN() has 3 IDs in it. How can I get this data in 1 query if the IDs are the same?

Comment: This seems like a simplified version of a larger problem you are trying to solve.  Is the IN clause generated by a sub-select?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL `IN` is a set operator. One of the first tasks the SQL optimizer does is to remove repeated elements in the **set**, since it doesn't make sense to have multiple equivalent values.

If you really want to get three rows, you could try something like:

```
select name, value, item_id from items where item_id = 9044 and tradeable = 1
union all
select name, value, item_id from items where item_id = 9044 and tradeable = 1
union all
select name, value, item_id from items where item_id = 3832 and tradeable = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to use a `left join`:

```
select i.name, i.value, ii.item_id
from (select 9044 as item_id union all
      select 9044 union all
      select 3832
     ) ii left join
     items i
     on i.item_id = ii.item_id and i.tradeable = 1;
```